# Edit Treeview in TYPO3 flux

Tags: typo3, fluid

I want to edit a sys category in a fluidcontent Template.
I am using:

- TYPO3 6.2.13
- flux 7.2.1
- fluidcontent 4.2.2
- fluidpages 3.2.3
- vhs 2.3.3

Trying this does alway says i have to select an element:

```
<flux:field.tree table="sys_category" parentField="parent" maxLevels="10" expandAll="1" name="syscategories" size="20" width="900">
    <flux:wizard.edit label="Edit" />
</flux:field.tree>
```

Adding the `flux:wizard.edit` to a `flux:field.relation` also don't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Create Folder and Add categories in it.

And Use below code. Where pid in flux:wizard.list and flux:wizard.add is your folder ID.

```
<flux:field.tree table="sys_category" parentField="parent" maxLevels="10" expandAll="1" name="syscategories" size="20" width="900" />
    <flux:field.input name="settings.systemcategoy" label="System Category">
        <flux:wizard.list label="List System Categories" hideParent="1" table="sys_category" pid="38" width="80" height="80" />
        <flux:wizard.edit label="Edit System Categories" width="80" height="80" openOnlyIfSelected="1" />
        <flux:wizard.add label="Add System Categories" hideParent="1" table="sys_category" pid="38" setValue="prepend" />   
    </flux:field.input>
```

Comment: Clicking the edit button, still opens a dialog saying that i have to select at least one element.

Comment: It means you have to first select category which you want to edit. <flux:field.tree table="sys_category" parentField="parent" maxLevels="10" expandAll="1" name="syscategories" size="20" width="900" /> This code Display Categories. From This List select category you want to edit then this message does not display.

Comment: That's right. I want to edit the selected category from the treeview. If you have many categories and subcategories, the list view does not display its subcategory. A treeview is more clear and usable.